# How to make buttons draggable

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is there a way to make buttons draggable? The standard way that works for other elements such as labels, doesn't work.

```
<Button Text="Hello">
      <Button.GestureRecognizers
              <DragGestureRecognizer CanDrag="True"/>  
     </Button.GestureRecognizers>
</Button>
```

thank you!

Comment: I don't think this is possible, for the simple reason that touching a button means pressing it. And pressing on a button, then dragging finger to the side, means you "changed your mind", it is a way to "cancel" the touch. So you would have two conflicting meanings to the touch. You'll need to have a "mode" button somewhere, that puts the UI into a "draggable" state. Then replace each button with something that looks like a button, but isn't really. Details TBD - investigating...

Comment: ... Solving this is more involved than I have time to do right now, sorry. google `xamarin forms data template selector for content view` for related discussions. Hopefully someone else will come along and make an answer with the code you need - I didn't find an existing discussion that exactly matched what you need to do. Its a fairly advanced topic, but if you attempt to follow one of those googled examples, please add the code you attempt to your question, and say where you get stuck. OR if you get it working, then add "Your Answer" below, so others learn too.

Comment: Thank you for help. I posted my solution below. If you happen to find it suboptimal, I'd welcome your insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it by assigning both tap and drag event to a label. Tap event is luckily not fired when dragging.

```
<Label Text="Hello">
    <Label.GestureRecognizers>              
       <DragGestureRecognizer CanDrag="True"
                              DragStarting="DragGestureRecognizer_DragStarting"/>
       <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
</Label>
```

Comment: Very nice - that is an approach that I did not think of.